# How can I run "msnodesqlv8" on a computer without internet

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have a Node.js API on a Windows computer without internet access and I need to access data from a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have the module "mssql" however I need to use Windows authentication. I found online that this method requires the module "msnodesqlv8," however when I install the module on an internet-connected device and then move the files onto the non-internet device, the module won't run. The error I receive when I run the API indicates that the module needs to be rebuilt. Whenever I run "npm rebuild," the build attempts to install the dependencies - which of course is not possible without internet.

To try to circumvent this issue, I removed the dependency list prior to rebuild, but the rebuild still snags trying to install "safe-buffer." I don't know where this install is getting triggered. When I search for "safe-buffer" in the project, no references to "safe-buffer" are found. My assumption is that a dependency is trying to use it and I have not skimmed through every dependency yet.

I also tried packing the "msnodesqlv8" module, then installing it from the .tgz file, but this produced the same errors.

One avenue I have not yet tried is packing the module on the internet device, then transerfing the .tgz file.

Any recommendations would be awesome - I am blocked until I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by downloading a prebuild from the [Github releases](https://github.com/timelorduk/node-sqlserver-v8/releases/). I noticed in the stack trace of the rebuild that the process was accessing a specific build from this link, so I moved it into the "prebuilds" folder where it was expecting it, and the module powered up on the next rebuild.

This process has to be replicated on every device, from workstation to servers, but it works. Just make sure you download the build that matches your system.